# how can i create a reg exp or array to change this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok guys i have been working on these, this is like my main project and im pretty anxious about it, i have been practicing but im still a newbie. My code is like this and it does what it has to do, but im thinking that it could be improved to be better and more reusable, sorry to spam if i am, i already asked on the spanish version of the website with no satisfactory answer, im new to web developing and to this site, i always read the content on this site to answer my questions but for this time i didnt know how to exactly use the previous answers to fix my code, since im new to web developing and im trying to use jquery bit by bit. As i said my question is how can i create an array or a reg exp that does all the things this code does? without having to use .replace function all those times

i have tried urlencode function, and tried to iterate over arrays on jquery but i still dont know how to do it properly.

```
$( ".linkbestia" ).each(function() {

lnk = $(this).text();
enlace= $(this).attr("href");
espacios=lnk.replace(" ","_");
maslimpio=espacios.replace("'","%27");
muchomaslimpio=maslimpio.replace("(","%28");
muchomuchomaslimpio=maslimpio.replace(")","%29");
nuevoenlace=$(this).attr("href",enlace+muchomuchomaslimpio);

});
```

the actual output is for example [codedquote'replaced space](http://localhost/url/url/in/url/url/codedquote%27replaced_space) as i said it already does what it has to do, but i know it can be improved, i hope you guys help me since in my country these kind of questions cant be answered without a ton of difficulties

what it does right now:

[what the user writes would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKCdg.png)

[the result would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/642b2.png)

Comment: How's your input looks like ?

Comment: what are you input, and what output you want ?

Comment: Hello could you provide an example string input and what you would want to be the output, I understand your code already does this but if I can see what you start with compared to what you want I may be able to notice a maybe nicer way.

Comment: the input would look like codedquote'replaced space, but the actual input is an url looking like these <a class="linknpc" href="url/in/url/url/"> </a> its already beeing replaced on php (that is made in order to help the users to add a url on my website), allow me to explain further, for example on these example the user would write something like this -beast/The'White Mob/beast- and it would output something like this <a class="linknpc" href="url/in/url/url/The%27White_Mob">The'White Mob</a> by the way guys thank you very much for taking interest on my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to take href from below:

```
<a class="linknpc" href="url/in/url/url/The%27White_Mob">
```

and expected output is

```
The'White_Mob
```

after you get the href and lets say the var enlace looks like below.

```
var enlace = "url/in/url/url/The%27White_Mob"
```

Below will first use String split on '/' to get all sections from href and from resultant array get the last element by pop() and use decodeURIComponent to decode the encoded uri.

```
var ans = decodeURIComponent(enlace.split('/').pop())
```

ans would now have the value: `The'White_Mob`

note: If the href ends with '/' then you need to adjust above solution accordingly

Comment: excuse me sir, it is really helping me but what i meant was the opposite of that i get this i mean the code does this (changes the empty url 'template') for the 'parameter' given allow me to show you, what i want to do, is to use a function or variable like the one you created to do all that the code does in less lines, so it could look more professional or clean, because i think that like that is fine because it does what it has to do, but i dont think that is the way it should be done. I will try to edit the question.